# jQuery not pulling hidden field value on content page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am running this script within a content page on my ASP.net site.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var satShifts = $('#hidSat').val();

            alert("Sat: " + satShifts);

        });
    </script>
```

On the page_Load event on the server I have this code:

```
        hidSat.Value = "2";
```

The variable comes back as undefined in the alert window. I have this same process on the master page with another script and it works flawlessly. Is this an issue because it is a content page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know,
if u use asp control in the content page,
the id is prefix with master name by .net compiler b4 render to html page.

So, here is my suggestion:

**inspect the output html file with FireBug or Chrome** 
and see the name of ur hidden field.
if it is different, then u need to assign the id to some variable in JS.
like:

```
var tmp = '<%=hidSat.CliendID %>';
```

then,

```
$(tmp).val();
```

if it doesn't work, try with `.html()` method.
it will return all html code within ur hidden field.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to below, since hidSat is server control.

```
var satShifts = $('#<%=hidSat.ClientID#').val();
```